# Doctrine one-to-many returning null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to map a **Milestones** to a **Project** but when I try to reference the relation it's always returning null.

The database looks perfect, the targetEntity paths are correct and the scheme is validating by using

```
doctrine:scheme:validate
```

#### project.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Planning\Readmodel\Project\Milestone\Milestone", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $milestones;
```

#### milestone.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Planning\Readmodel\Project\Project", inversedBy="milestones", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projectId", referencedColumnName="projectId")
 */
private $project;
```

But when I try to get the milestone I get null using:

```
$this->milestones;
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Where do you try to get the milestone ?

Comment: Can you post the code where you want to retrieve milestones? Are the data you want to get already in database, or are you trying to insert a new relation?

Comment: What DOZ said. Can you provide more context around the line $this->milestones;  where are you using this line to call the private $milestones property?

Comment: Faced with this problem too, did you solved it?

Comment: Oh my this is way to long ago, can't even remember I ever posted this, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Your owning entity definition i.e `Project` looks fine to me but your inversed entity i.e  `Milestone` has a problem in `JoinColumn` annotation in `JoinColumn` annotation `name` relates to the column of your current entity which hold the relation to project entity but in `referencedColumnName` you have to provide the column of your parent entity that is primary key of project entity which should be `referencedColumnName="id"`

So your annotation for milestone entity should be like

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Planning\Readmodel\Project\Project", inversedBy="milestones", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $project;
```

According to the official docs [**5.11. Mapping Defaults**](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#mapping-defaults)

> The name of the join table defaults to a combination of the simple,
>   unqualified class names of the participating classes, separated by an
>   underscore character. The names of the join columns default to the
>   simple, unqualified class name of the targeted class followed by
>   “_id”. The referencedColumnName always defaults to “id”, just as in
>   one-to-one or many-to-one mappings.

Make sure to update your database by running doctrine update command

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in both columns: projectId is used as the name of the key (not my favorite naming convention but I have to). So your proposal didn't solve it. Thanks!